# Does it matter how fast I mash the keys when wiggling or struggling?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

I.e. does the number of keypresses count, or it is a predetermined speed for both that creeps forward as long as I press <kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>D</kbd> or                     within a predetermined time (e.g. once every half second)

Comment: I don't think it matters, progress seems to move at a consistent speed as long as you're pressing the keys above a certain speed. I kind of wish they would take this out, it's pretty annoying to have to button mash as frequently and for as long as the game asks you to.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't do anything if you go faster. The best method is to go slow and steady, like click once every half a second. You could also just copy the example it shows as you get on the beast's back.